# Using regular expressions in Linux with grep

Tags: linux, terminal, regex, grep

I can't get this simple regular expression to work for matching emails:

```
'\w*(?:\.\w*)*@\w*(?:\.\w*)*\w\{2,5\}'
```

It should be working as I have tested it with regex pal 
and it works just fine.
I think there's a problem with optional character class
but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is it intended to do?

Comment: To match the email.

Comment: Then it's wrong. A lot more than `\w`ord characters are permitted in an e-mail address. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax.

Comment: The actual specification is http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I'm testing it on a certain email - email.something@blah.mailas.com

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Comment: Thanks, but I won't be using this expression for anything, only for testing.. I just want to know WHY it doesn't work? Should I use egrep or something?

Comment: Egrep with expression '\w*(\.(\w*))*@\w*(\.(\w*))*\.\w{2,5}' worked, I guess there's no optional character class when using (e)grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use grep with perl regular expression (`-P` option) which supports lookahead assertions like `(?:  )`. Also curly braces shouldn't be escaped.

Try:

```
grep -P '\w*(?:\.\w*)*@\w*(?:\.\w*)*\w{2,5}'
```

Since perl expressions are experimental feature in GNU grep you may want to change `(?:  )` to `(  )` and user extended expressions (`-E`):

```
grep -E '\w*(\.\w*)*@\w*(\.\w*)*\w{2,5}'
```

Some of the extended expression implementations do not support curly braces `{` and `}`. For portability you can use basic regular expressions.

To use basic regular expressions escape `(` and `)` and leave also `{` and `}` escaped.

```
grep '\w*\(\.\w*\)*@\w*\(\.\w*\)*\w\{2,5\}'
```